# OpenCASCADE: extracting shape based on color from a STEP object

Tags: c++, step, opencascade

If a user has defined curves or faces within a STEP file with colors, I'm able to read in the colors from the STEP file and create a list with this snippet:

```
Handle_XCAFDoc_ColorTool colorList = XCAFDoc_DocumentTool::ColorTool(STEPDocument->Main());

// List colors in the STEP File
TDF_LabelSequence colors;
colorList->GetColors(colors);
```

I am having trouble extracting a shape, assembly, or component based on a given color.  Ideally, I would like to extract a TopoDS_Shape from a method that uses color in such a way that I can cycle through the list of colors and dump out a shape.  Any thoughts?  Any hints on classes to look at or strategies will be helpful.